# How do you define and use curry and uncurry (Prelude functions) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, currying

How can I use `curry` and `uncurry` prelude functions in Haskell?

Moreover, why do the following definitions throw an error when loaded?

```
curry' :: ((a -> b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
curry' f = \x y -> f (x, y)

uncurry' :: a -> b -> c -> ((a -> b) -> c)
uncurry' f = \(x,y) -> f x y
```

Comment: Your definitions are right, you just made a little error with the types: you want to go to/from a function that takes a tuple `((a, b) -> c)` and not another function as you have now. So `(a, b)` instead of `(a -> b)`.

Answer (score 13):

You're getting errors because your type signatures are wrong, you should be using tuples instead of functions for the `a` and `b` arguments:

```
curry' :: ((a, b) -> c) -> a -> b -> c
uncurry' :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
```

Also, notice the parentheses I added to `uncurry'`s type, those are important in this case.  What you have is equivalent to

```
uncurry' :: a -> (b -> (c -> ((a -> b) -> c)))
```

Which is not the same, this is a function that takes 3 arguments and produces a function instead of a function that takes a 2 argument function and returns a function of one tuple argument.

You could use these functions like

```
> uncurry (+) (1, 2)
3
> curry fst 1 2
1
> curry snd 1 2
2
```

(I didn't see any other `Prelude` functions that take tuples as arguments)

EDIT: At chi's request, here's a more visual explanation of that last sentence:

```
a -> (b -> (c -> ((a, b) -> c)))
```

is the type of a function that takes 3 arguments `a`, `b`, and `c`, and returns a function of type `(a, b) -> c`.

```
(a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
```

is the type of a function that takes a single argument `a -> b -> c` and returns a function `(a, b) -> c`.

Comment: My brain parser computed for a while on the last sentence, before realizing the structure "this is ... instead of ...". I was parsing it as "and produces ... instead of ...". Maybe you can add some visual aid for human parsers. :-)